# Disable generating PDB files in MsBuild

Tags: c#, debugging, build, msbuild

I'm looking to squeeze some more speed out of my build and was wondering if I could instruct msbuild to not generate PDB files.  I'm passing the `Configuration=Release` and `DebugSymbols=false` property with no luck.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You may have PDB generation in your release configuration. Add this to your release settings:

```
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>None</DebugType>
```

You can also, do this in your project configuration inside visual studio. [Disable PDB Generation](http://gchandra.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/disable-pdp-file-generation-in-release-mode/)

Also, if running MSBuild from the command line, the command line arguments would be

```
MSBuild.exe YourProject.csproj /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None
```

Comment: I found the MSBuild version worked with "/p:DebugType=None" alone (i.e. didn't create the pdb file). It didn't seem to need "/p:DebugSymbols=false" too. Is there any advantage to having both?

Comment: It seems that both arguments do the same thing, so you just need one or the other. More info can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

Comment: Putting it in the project file means its guaranteed to always be disabled, so if you were distributing the project without any make batch file etc this would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Setting `/p:DebugSymbols=false` had no effect with `Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 15.8.166+gd4e8d81a88 for .NET Core`. I had to use `/p:DebugType=None`.

Comment: Does not work for a WinForms project. The pdbs are still added.