# TeamCity Using OctoPack - Isn't Excluding Superfluous Files

Tags: teamcity, nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I'm just looking at streamlining the nuget packages that are coming out of my build system and I'm stuck on how to only package the files that are required.

I have several configurations sharing a Root VCS checkout.  I have a configuration that runs a debug build with unit tests.  I also have a release configuration that does a release build, this configuration then also uses the TeamCity OctoPack plugin to create the nuget packages.

What I want to achieve is the building of nuget packages that don't contain the `*.pdb` and `*.xml` documentation files as these aren't required for the release deployment.

I've looked through this page on the OD site:

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack

And according to this page OctoPack should only package up the required files by default.  I'm not entirely clear on how or what needs to be done to get around this problem as it doesn't appear to be working as described.

It seems that one solution would be to provide a nuspec file for the projects I'm looking to deply but I'm also wondering if there is something I'm missing before I head off down that route.

I also have some MEF plugins that are copied in post build events and these aren't included in the nuget packages when in fact they are needed for the application to run.  I think I need to get explicit with a nuspec file but would like to confirm this.

What is the simplest way of achieving what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running the later versions of OctoPack, in your release build you can set a system parameter `system.DebugType = None` which will get passed to the OctoPack build scripts and prevent the PDB's being created.

This simply overrides the setting defined in your csproj msbuild file (assuming C#), so you can use it wherever you want to prevent PDB's being created at the build configuration level (not just OctoPack).  I generally prefer this approach as it prevents side-effects in your build from changes by developers in the project file.

As for the xml files, I haven't actually tried this, but you can try a similar approach and create a system parameter `system.DocumentationFile = ""` to blank out the output.

Comment: Looking though the documentation it appears the setting is actually called `DebugSymbols=false` it seems that `DebugType` defined the level of debug info MSBuild will generate.

Comment: That's interesting - it may be an MSBuild version difference.  I'm running several builds with just the `DebugType` property.  Others seem to notice the [same behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/773834/2293059)

Comment: That is odd.  I've not tested yet as I'm doing a full review of my entire build process at the moment.  Will report what I find out.

Comment: I've been working on this for hours now and I give up.  OctoPack just isn't very reliable or smart as far as I can tell. I updated to latest version and now its started to complete ignore a stack of required files.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make sure that the files have been removed there are a couple of ways you can do this. Modify your deployment process to:

1. Execute your own custom PowerShell script in that removes the files
2. Include a script module from the Octopus Library to the same. Check out the [File System - Clean Directory](http://library.octopusdeploy.com/#!/step-template/actiontemplate-file-system-clean-directory) from the [Octopus Library](http://library.octopusdeploy.com/#!/listing)

Comment: Both of these seem a little backward in going forward to me.  Especially the cleaning of files after a deployment, that just doesn't make sense to me.