# How to stop generate pdb files in Release package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, continuous-integration, publish, devops

I'm trying to implement a CD/CI pipeline on TFS. I've created the build, and all the steps has been successfully, except Publish symbols path.

I'm receiving this error message:

2019-09-12T11:34:17.9788901Z ##[error]Indexed source information could not be retrieved from 'E:\buildAgent_work\96\s\Branch\Branche\Api\bin\AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity.pdb'. Symbol indexes could not be retrieved.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed the problem. I had just to change to Release, instead of Debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How to stop generate pdb files in Release package

This issue seems to be:

- The default value for  is portable - the new portable PDB.
- TFS 2017 can't read the new portable PDB format.

Some possible workarounds for:

- upgrade to TFS 2018
- exclude AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity.pdb when publishing symbols
- Build `AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity` from source and set the `<DebugType>None</DebugType>` in the project.

Since the `AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity.pdb` comes from the nuget package [AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity/3.3.100.73), we could **not** use the following setting to [disable PDB Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773796/disable-generating-pdb-files-in-msbuild):

```
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>None</DebugType>
```

So, we could update TFS to 2018 or **exclude AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity.pdb when publishing symbols**.

To exclude AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity.pdb when publishing symbols, we could use File matching patterns reference in the option Search pattern of Publish symbols path task:

```
**/bin/**/*.pdb
!**/bin/**/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.pdb
```

[image]

Hope this helps.