# dotnet publish CLI exclude .pdb

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0, .net-7.0

In .NET 7, I do:

```
dotnet publish --self-contained --configuration Release --runtime win7-x64 --output myapp
```

How do I prevent `.pdb` files in the result? Ideally, just using the CLI?

Are there any additional steps I can take to decrease the result size?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16975#issuecomment-597612660

Comment: @LeiYang [The successor to .NET 6?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-7-preview-1/)

Comment: sorry, i'm not aware of it. is .net advancing so fast?

Comment: @LeiYang .NET 6 was released Nov 2021, .NET 5 was released Nov 2020, .NET Core 3.1 was released Dec 2019. It seems to be once a year. A prerelease in 2022 for .NET 7 seems to fit well into that timeline.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable generating PDB files in MsBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773796/disable-generating-pdb-files-in-msbuild)

Comment: Note that if you are experiencing .pdb files **and loads of other junk files** in your publishing directory, you are probably suffering from [this issue][1] which is reported to Microsoft [here][2].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16975), there are two ways you can disable symbols.

You can either edit the .csproj file to add these two entries:

```xml
<DebugType>None</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
```

Or you can pass the following as part of the `dotnet publish` command:

```
/p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false
```

For example:

```
dotnet publish /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false --self-contained --configuration Release --runtime win7-x64 --output myapp
```

Comment: I think, those properties are related to **build**, so they have no effect if you run **dotnet publish --no-build**

Comment: @Ilyan Yes, they are MSBuild options. You can also pass the same options to `dotnet build` I believe.

Comment: When I try this and I but this two lines in my .pubxml file I get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77071059/the-debug-type-specified-in-the-dependency-context-could-be-parsed-asp-core-er

Answer (score 17):

To disable `.pdb` files **only for release**, add this to your `Project.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
  <DebugType>None</DebugType>
</PropertyGroup>
```