# The debug type specified in the dependency context could be parsed - ASP.NET Core error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, publish, .net-7.0

When I publish my ASP.NET Core app to IIS, I get error but if I run my app in Visual Studio debug or release, it works fine.

The error message I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The debug type specified in the dependency context could be parsed. The debug type value 'false' is not supported

The error stack is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The debug type specified in the dependency context could be parsed. The debug type value 'false' is not supported.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CSharpCompiler.GetEmitOptions(CompilationOptions dependencyContextOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CSharpCompiler.EnsureOptions()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.CSharpCompiler.get_ParseOptions()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.RazorRuntimeCompilationMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<AddServices>b__3(RazorProjectEngineBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Create(RazorConfiguration configuration, RazorProjectFileSystem fileSystem, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.RazorRuntimeCompilationMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.<>c.<AddServices>b__2_2(IServiceProvider s)
   at Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection.WindsorRegistrationHelper.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<RegisterServiceDescriptor>b__0(IKernel c)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1.<>c__DisplayClass85_0`1.<UsingFactoryMethod>b__0(IKernel k, ComponentModel m, CreationContext c)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.FactoryMethodActivator`1.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernel(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.TryResolveCore(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency, Object& value)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, Arguments additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy, Boolean ignoreParentContext)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, Arguments additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.ResolveAll(Type service, Arguments arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveAll(Type service, Arguments arguments)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.SpecializedResolvers.CollectionResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection.MsCompatibleCollectionResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.TryResolveCore(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency, Object& value)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernelByType(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.ResolveFromKernel(CreationContext context, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.TryResolveCore(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency, Object& value)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.DefaultDependencyResolver.Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.CreateConstructorArguments(ConstructorCandidate constructor, CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.Instantiate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.DefaultComponentActivator.InternalCreate(CreationContext context)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator.AbstractComponentActivator.Create(CreationContext context, Burden burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.AbstractLifestyleManager.CreateInstance(CreationContext context, Boolean trackedExternally)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.SingletonLifestyleManager.Resolve(CreationContext context, IReleasePolicy releasePolicy)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, Arguments additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy, Boolean ignoreParentContext)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, Arguments arguments, IReleasePolicy policy, Boolean ignoreParentContext)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, Arguments arguments)
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve(Type service)
   at Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection.ScopedWindsorServiceProvider.ResolveInstanceOrNull(Type serviceType, Boolean isOptional)
   at Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection.ScopedWindsorServiceProvider.GetServiceInternal(Type serviceType, Boolean isOptional)
   at Castle.Windsor.MsDependencyInjection.ScopedWindsorServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String name, String pattern, Object defaults, Object constraints, Object dataTokens)
   at Sibies.UrbanX.Web.Startup.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__4_2(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at Sibies.UrbanX.Web.Startup.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Sibies.UrbanX.Web.Startup.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happened after I try this [dotnet publish CLI exclude .pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476329/dotnet-publish-cli-exclude-pdb) and I put in my publish (.pubxml file) config this lines:

```
<DebugType>None</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
```

I solve by removing this two lines.